# Given a matrix $A\in M_3(Z_{11})$, calculate $\det(3A)^{-1}$ given $\det A=4$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, inverse

$(3A)^{-1} = \frac{1}{3}A^{-1}$

So that, $\det(3A)^{-1} = (\frac{1}{3})^3\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{27}*\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{9}$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks fine to me

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Actually, $3^3 \times 4 = 9$ in $\mathbb Z_{11}$. Fractions & matrix algebra work the same over any field.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Why would you expect the equations to do anything with $\mathbb R$, if the question clearly states $\mathbb Z_{11}$?

Comment: @lisyarus Yes, I see what you mean. I got carried away  by the $\frac 19$ notation, after all that is looking more like a real number than an element of $\mathbb Z_{11}$. Ok, I will delete the preceding comments.

Answer (score 1):

As you work in $\mathbf Z/11\mathbf Z$, you cannot really use fractions, which live i, $\mathbf Q$, and you have to replace $\frac13$ and $\frac14$ with $3^{-1}=4$ and $4^{-1}=3$ repectively. Other than that, the formulæ are correct, if they are interpreted properly. This
$$\det\bigl((3A)^{-1}\bigr)=\bigl(\det(3A)\bigr)^{-1}=(3^3\det A)^{-1}=(5\cdot4)^{-1}=9^{-1}=5. $$

Comment: I don't really see why we should always treat ${1\over n}$ as an element of $\mathbb Q$ and not a syntactic substitute for $n^{-1}$.

Comment: You can, but in my opinion, you have to warn about it. It is associated with the notion of field of fractions of an integral domain, and it's  confusional for beginners.

Comment: You have a point, but the $\frac{1}{27}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{9}$ part of the question indicates that the OP clearly understands what's happening.